# How do I simplify this jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a few HTML pages that contain a list of thumbnails of varying quantity (peaking at 38 on one page), and I'm using the following jQuery to store the ID attribute from each of them when clicked, in the currPhoto variable:

```
$('#thumbnav a:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
currPhoto = $('#0').attr('id');
});

$('#thumbnav a:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
currPhoto = $('#1').attr('id');
});

$('#thumbnav a:nth-child(3)').click(function() {
currPhoto = $('#2').attr('id');
});

$('#thumbnav a:nth-child(4)').click(function() {
currPhoto = $('#3').attr('id');
});

$('#thumbnav a:nth-child(5)').click(function() {
currPhoto = $('#4').attr('id');
});
```

...etc, continuing with 33 more of those.

I'm certain there must be a way to simplify this into one block of code, but I'm not experienced at using jQuery so I can't for the life of me work out what that might be.

Comment: What does the HTML look like and why are you using nth-child so much?

Comment: Please don't use `$(this).attr('id')` (or `$(this).prop('id')`), `this.id` will retrieve the `id` perfectly well, and more cheaply than with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking at *all* the `a` elements under `#thumbnav`, you don't need individual selectors:

```
$('#thumbnav a').click(function() {
  currPhoto = this.id;  // `this` will be the clicked `a` element
});
```

Comment: And `this.id` will retrieve the `id`; why would you use jQuery's `attr()` (or even `prop()`) to retrieve a property of the DOM node?

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using exactly this, except I substituted `this.id` with `index()` as the ids referred to are in a different section of the HTML. Apologies for not clarifying that properly.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way will be with a for loop:

```
   for(var i = 0 ; i < 33 ;i++)
    {
       $('#thumbnav a:nth-child(' + i + ')').click(function() {
              currPhoto = $('#' + (i-1)).attr('id');
        });
    }
```

A better way will be to tag the `a`'s with a `class` and use it as a selector:

```
   <a class="cls">Content</a>
   $('.cls').click(function() {
          currPhoto = $(this).closest('.cls').attr('id');
    });
```

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) gets the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Comment: Personally, I suggest `document.getElementById(i).id` for simple speed optimization

Answer (score 0):

You should bind only one event on parent instead of one event for each link especially since you have so many on one page:

```
$('#thumbnav').on('click', 'a', function() {
    currPhoto = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

This approach will also allow you to dynamically add/remove links without the need of binding new events.